# Highlighting a specific row in a jQuery dataTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, datatables

I've been trying to replicate this behavior what with a different approach. I've got two pages:

- **edit.php?id=45** is a form where the record can be modified, and onSubmit it goes to table.php?id=45
- **table.php?id=** holds a datatable, on which each row has a first hidden column that holds the record unique id. If the **id=45** querystring is present, the row that has the row with the 45 id should be highlighted with a classname (similar when going back to the inbox from an opened email on Gmail).

The problem is that I cant seem to find the row through any of the examples. BTW, I am using a serverside data source, so I can't just use this:

```
$("#datatable_test tbody tr").find("td:contains("+id+")").addClass("highlight");
```

So, I tried the fnGetNodes approach with no luck (http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_post_init.html):

```
var id = <?$_GET['id']?>;
$("tr", datatable_test.fnGetNodes()).each(function(data){
    $(this).find("td:contains("+id+")").addClass("highlight");
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to include your record id as an attribute of a visible `td` and use that to find your row. Some like...

```
oTable.$('[data-id=7688]').parents('tr').addClass('highlight')
```

If you are unable to change the markup, here's a rather convoluted way to find the row:

```
var data = oTable.fnGetData()
// assumes that the first column contains your recordId,
// that the record id cell markup is just <div>recordId</div> and
// that you have available to you the underscore.js library
var row = _.findWhere(data, {0: "<div>" + recordId + "</div>"})
var index = _.indexOf(data, row)
oTable.$('tr:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('highlight')
```

This attempt is a first stab; I am sure it can be cleaned up a bit.